# Adobe AEM - resource deny access per ip

Tags: adobe, aem

i'm working with Adobe AEM 6 SP2 and i need to filter the access to some resources like /etc/importers/bulkeditor.html. I need allow to users into the VPN but i need deny to the rest of the users (internet access).
I thought to use a http filter but it does not seem very efficient.
Also i researched about the rules of the dispatcher but can not find how to do it.

Somebody can help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that this is an author instance and therefore it sounds like the better thing, and best practice, would be to deny access via ACL's and not IP Address.

Answer (score 0):

If you still need to deny access per IP, (which I doubt for the reason mentioned by victor) then you can configure two virtual host at the dispatcher level, one for your intranet and one for your internet and a deny rule for the internet and an allow rule for the intranet.